# VHDL Logic produces wrong result when using higher frequencies

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl

I don't have much experience with VHDL, so excuse me if it's stupid boring question, but I couldn't find appropriate answer. I have code that is a bit simplified here.

```
process (sys_clk, reset):

  begin
    if reset = '0' then
     -- reseting code
    elsif rising_edge(sys_clk) then
        if data_ready = '1' and old_data_ready = '0' then -- rising edge of asynchronous sig
            -- update few registers, and assigning values to few signals
        elsif error_occured = '1' and old_error_occurred = '0' then
          -- update few registers, and assigning values to few signals (same registers and  signal as above)
        end if;
        old_data_ready <= data_ready;
        old_error_occured <= error_occured;
    end if;

   end process;
```

Signal is kept much longer high than period of sys_clk is, but it's not know for how long. It varies.
These IFs result in two (one each) registers and an AND circuit. I believe you know that.
This worked, but very badly. The were errors to often. So I made special project using two processes. One active on rising edge of data_ready and one on error_occured. But I could use it just to increment and decrement to separate counters. I used that to verify that problem with my code is that sometimes this rising edge detection does not work. sys_clk is 27MHz, and I made much bigger project using that same frequency and they worked well. But there was no detection of rising edge of asynchronous signals this way. So I reduced frequency to 100kHz, because I don't really need higher frequencies. And that solved my problem.

But just for curiosity, what is the best way to test for rising edge of asynchronous signal when few of these signal affect same registers and device needs to work on higher frequencies?

I use Altera Quartus II and Cyclone II FPGA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signal you are sampling is truly asynchronous, you have to deal with the issue of metastability. If the data_ready signal is in a metastable state exactly on sys_clk's rising edge, old_data_ready and the first if-statement might see different versions of data_ready. Also, you have an asynchronous reset. If the reset signal is released exactly when the data_ready is changing, it may result in data_ready being sampled to different values though out your system. A simulator will not reveal metastability problems, because the code is logically correct.

To circumvent these problems, have asynchronous reset between modules, but synchronous within.
Also, synchronize any signal coming from a different clock domain. A synchronizer is a couple of flip flops placed closely together. When the signal passes through the FFs, any metastability issues will be resolved before it reaches your logic. There is a formula for calculating mean time between failure (MTBF) due to metastability in FPGAs. I won't recite it, but what is basically says is that using this simple method reduces MTBF from seconds to billions of years.

VHDL synchronizer:

```
process(clk, rst) is
begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    if(rst = '0') then
      data_ready_s1 <= '0';
      data_ready_s2 <= '0';
    else
      data_ready_s1 <= data_ready;
      data_ready_s2 <= data_ready_s1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Use data_ready_s2 in your module.
Then you constrain the path between the flipflops in the UCF file:

```
TIMEGRP "FF_s1" = FFS("*_s1") FFS("*_s1<*>");
TIMEGRP "FF_s2" = FFS("*_s2") FFS("*_s2<*>");
TIMESPEC TS_SYNC = FROM "FF_s1" TO "FF_s2" 2 ns DATAPATHONLY;
```

Comment: @Marko: For a start, try to determine if metastability is the problem, by simply adding the synchronization flip-flop for both `data_ready` and `error_occured`.  See [Wikipedia Metastability in electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability_in_electronics) and the related external links for more info about the topic.

Comment: Thank you both. Where can I found out how to implement synchronization flip-flops in VHDL (and how that looks in schematic)? Do you have any advice?

Comment: Note that OP states Altera but UCF is a Xilinx constraint.  You also want a false path on the input to data_ready_s1.